# Одностраничный сайт на html

Tags: html

Скажите, пожалуйста.
Сделал на сайте две формы для имени и адреса. И кнопку сабмит.

**Вопрос 1**. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки имя и фамилия сохранялись на этой же странице?

**Вопрос 2**: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы все данные на странице очищались в определенное время?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Данные можно сохранить на странице при помощи JS, но они в любой момент они могут быть утеряны, да и видеть их будет только человек добавивший их.(т.к. сохранены они на клиентской стороне, браузере пользователя)
Чтобы сохранять и выводить необходимые Вам данные, вам нужна серверная сторона.

Т.е.
Клиент <=> HTML страница <=> Сервер

Нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку, данные отправлялись на сервер, после чего там обрабатывались и сохранялись. В последующем Вы сможете делать с этими данными все что только захотите. Но средствами HTML этого не добиться.

Answer (score 4):

Ну а вот простенькая реализация на js, так как думаю, что автор не о сервере речь вел.

```js
var message;

function letsdoit() {
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
message = document.getElementById('welcomemess');
var ticks = document.getElementById('ticks').value;
message.innerHTML = "Привет, " + fname.value + " " + lname.value;
setTimeout(ticktock, 1000*ticks);
}

function ticktock() {
message.innerHTML='';
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomemess"></div>
<input id="fname" placeholder="Имя">
<input id="lname" placeholder="Фамилия">
<input id="ticks" placeholder="Секунд до скрытия">
<button onclick="letsdoit()">Отправить</button>
```

А вообще, да, конечно сервак

**UPD:** Добавил очищение данных спустя заданное количество секунд

Answer (score 2):

Можно хранить заполненные данные в браузере посетителя. Разумеется, они будут видны только ему. Другие посетители страницы будут иметь дело каждый со своими данными. Иначе нужен общий сервер.

Пример использует `localStorage` и сохраняет заполненные данные, даже если браузер закрыть. В песочнице SO не работает, вот работающая [копия на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/dppp9hwa/).

```js
var people = []
  ,saved = localStorage.getItem("people")
  ,in_name = document.getElementById('in-name')
  ,in_addr = document.getElementById('in-addr')
;

if( saved) {
  people = JSON.parse(saved);
  render();
}

document.getElementById('btn-save').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(){
    people.push({
      name: in_name.value,
      addr: in_addr.value
    });
    localStorage.setItem("people", JSON.stringify( people));
    render();
  }
);

function render() {
  var div = document.getElementById('out'), i, html = '', p;
  for( i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    p = people[i];
    html += '<dt>'+p.name+'</dt><dd>'+p.addr+'</dd>';
  }
  div.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="in-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
<input id="in-addr" type="text" name="addr" placeholder="Адрес">
<button id="btn-save">Сохранить</button>
<dl id="out"></dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранять в сессии или куки, например.
Когда нажимается на кнопку, отправляется запрос скрипту-обработчику.
Принимайте им данные из нужных полей, например, так:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['input_name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
```

А при загрузке страницы:

```
$name = "";
if(!empty($_SESSION['input_name'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['input_name'];
}
```

Только сайт уже не на html получится, а на php.
Можете, конечно, использовать библиотеку jquery-cookie, с ее помощью сохранять данные в cookie и так же при генерации страницы проверять наличие содержимого полей в них, но уже средствами jquery.